# Display HTML special characters stored in JavaScript string

Tags: javascript, htmlspecialchars

I need to dynamically append a text to a `<div>` with JavaScript. This text is retrieved from a database and it also contains special character as **ü** or **'**. Now i'm using the `createTextNode()` but the HTML special characters like `&xxxx;` aren't "resolved" then the output isn't correct.

Is there any method to print out the text with special character displayed correctly?

Thanks for any reply

Comment: Use JavaScript notation for the special characters instead of HTML notation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it will do exactly what you want if you use innerHTML instead of createTextNode().

Answer (score 1):

For ü you will have to use `\xfc`

```
<div id="result"></div>
$('#result').text('\xfc');
```

Here is working example: http://jsfiddle.net/djnnvc7m/

And here is the symbol table. Refer to 'HEX' column in table. 
http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

Comment: Or simply `'ü'`? Just make sure to transfer the script (or whatever it is) with the matching encoding and it'll work.